# Prove convexity of $f(x_1,x_2,x_3)=\frac{x_1^2+x_1+1}{x_2+x_3}$ over $\{(x_1,x_2,x_3) : x_2,x_3\gt0\}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

> Prove **convexity** of $$f(x_1,x_2,x_3)=\frac{x_1^2+x_1+1}{x_2+x_3}$$ over $\{(x_1,x_2,x_3) : x_2,x_3\gt0\}$

I am looking for an easy (or relatively easy) way to show $f$ is convex.
I tried to split the function into:
$$\frac{x_1^2}{x_2+x_3}+\frac{1}{x_2+x_3}+\frac{x_1}{x_2+x_3}$$
The first and the second functions are convex:

- The first is convex because it's quadratic-over-linear which is convex;
- The second is convex because it's linear change of variables of $\frac{1}{x}$ which is convex over $x>0$.

I stuck proving the third one. I found it's Hessian matrix. Let $g(x)=\frac{x_1}{x_2+x_3}$.

$$\nabla ^2g(x)=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & \frac{-1}{(x_2+x_3)^2} & \frac{-1}{(x_2+x_3)^2} \\
\frac{-1}{(x_2+x_3)^2} & \frac{2x_1}{(x_2+x_3)^3} & \frac{2x_1}{(x_2+x_3)^3} \\
\frac{-1}{(x_2+x_3)^2} & \frac{2x_1}{(x_2+x_3)^3} & \frac{2x_1}{(x_2+x_3)^3}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

It suffices to show $\nabla g(x)\succeq0$, but I failed to do so. Last hope is calculating eigenvalues, but it seems too difficult. By the way, I can't use *level-sets*.
Maybe there's an eaier way to show its convexity.

Please advise.

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you can write $x_1^2+x_1+1=(x_1+1/2)^2+3/4$, and split it this way to get rid of the problematic $x_1$ term.

Comment: @Momo Yes! Then it's just affine change of variables over quad-over-linear $\frac{x_1^2}{x_2}$ which is convex! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$g$ is not convex, as $(2,2)$-entry of $\nabla^2 g(x)$ is negative when $x_1$ is negative.

We have $\nabla f(x) = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{2x_1+1}{x_2+x_3} \\ - \frac{x_1^2+x_1+1}{(x_2+x_3)^2} \\ - \frac{x_1^2+x_1+1}{(x_2+x_3)^2}\end{bmatrix}$.

$$\nabla^2 f(x) = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{2}{x_2+x_3} & - \frac{2x_1+1}{(x_2+x_3)^2} & - \frac{2x_1+1}{(x_2+x_3)^2} \\ - \frac{2x_1+1}{(x_2+x_3)^2}  & \frac{2(x_1^2+x_1+1)}{(x_2+x_3)^3} & \frac{2(x_1^2+x_1+1)}{(x_2+x_3)^3}\\ - \frac{2x_1+1}{(x_2+x_3)^2} & \frac{2(x_1^2+x_1+1)}{(x_2+x_3)^3} & \frac{2(x_1^2+x_1+1)}{(x_2+x_3)^3}\end{bmatrix}$$

One possible way to check positive semidefiniteness is by examine the determinant of each principal minor is nonnegative.

Since the second row and the third row is identitcal, the determinant is $0$. Also $|a_{23}|=0$.

Notice that $|a_{11}|>0$. Since $x_1^2+x_1+1 \ge \frac34> 0$, we have $|a_{22}|=|a_{33}|>0$.

$$|a_{12}|=|a_{13}|=\frac1{(x_2+x_3)^4}[4(x_1^2+x_1+1)-(2x_1+1)^2]=\frac{3}{(x_2+x_3)^4}>0.$$

Hence, it is convex.

Comment: You are right, the third-degree in the Hessian was a typo. I know that **positive** principal minors imply *positive definiteness*, but I am not sure it works for positive **semi-definiteness** (with non-negative minors). Are you sure about that? Thank you for the detailed answer.

Comment: I checked a little bit and it seems that for telling anything about *positive semi-definiteness*, **all** the minors need to be nonnegative (and not only the principal minors).

Comment: Refers to theorem $6$ in [here](http://web.mit.edu/14.102/www/notes/soc.pdf). To check for positive definiteness, we check for all positive **leading** principal minors. To check for positive semidefiniteness, we check for all nonnegative principal minors.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Perhaps the first $n-1$ leading principal minors being positive and the determinant being nonnegative are enough to guarantee positive semidefiniteness. I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an easy approach:

We need that $g(x,y) = x^2/y$ is convex on $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R^+$, this follows e.g. from the theory of the 'perspective function'.

Then, we write
\begin{align*}
f(x_1, x_2, x_3) &= \frac{(x_1+1/2)^2 + 3/4}{x_2 + x_3}
\\&=
g(x_1 + 1/2, x_2 + x_3) + \frac{3/4}{x_2 + x_3}.
\end{align*}
Now, convexity follows easily.